# how to send data from the view to the header or the navigationBar

Tags: django, view, django-templates

I have a Django website that has a **navigation bar** where I need to display the user and the group that the user belongs to in the navigation bar in order to make this information visible on all pages.

Until now I am able to send these data items to a specific page but not to the header.

## views.py

```
def home(request):

 #print(User.groups.get())
 print(request.session.keys())
 if request.session.has_key('theUser'):
  authed=request.session['theUser']
  if request.session.has_key('group'):
   sections=request.session['group']
   return render(request,'./mainpage.html',{'sections':sections,'authed':authed})
  else:
   authed=None
 else:
  authed=None

 return render(request,'./Login.html',{'authed':authed})
```

Where I am sending **{'sections':sections,'authed':authed}** 
to **mainpage.html**

## mainpage.html

```
<div id='left-column-Input' class="formInput" include="select()">
        {{user.get_username}}|{{sections}}
```

What I need is to send the data to the header or the **base file**.

## base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static '/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' %}"></script>
        <link rel= "icon" type= "image/png" href="{% static 'img/logo_title/icon-AddressBar.png'%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/search.css'%}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/style.css'%}">
    </head>
<body>
    <img class="logoMM" src="{% static 'img/logoMM.png' %}" alt="Smiley face" />
    <!-- <div class="wrap"> -->
   <div class="wrap search Horizontal-scale">
   <!-- <div class="Horizontal-scale"> -->
      <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
        <svg aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="search"  role="img" viewBox="0 -20 530 530"><path fill="currentColor" d="M505 442.7L405.3 343c-4.5-4.5-10.6-7-17-7H372c27.6-35.3 44-79.7 44-128C416 93.1 322.9 0 208 0S0 93.1 0 208s93.1 208 208 208c48.3 0 92.7-16.4 128-44v16.3c0 6.4 2.5 12.5 7 17l99.7 99.7c9.4 9.4 24.6 9.4 33.9 0l28.3-28.3c9.4-9.4 9.4-24.6.1-34zM208 336c-70.7 0-128-57.2-128-128 0-70.7 57.2-128 128-128 70.7 0 128 57.2 128 128 0 70.7-57.2 128-128 128z"></path></svg>
     </button>
     <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="search">

    <!-- <div class="Horizontal-scale"> -->
    <label for="toggle">&#9776;</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>

  <div id="container" class="Horizontal-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">main</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">search</a></li>
               {% if authed is not None %}

        <li><a href="#" id="logMeOut">logout</a></li>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(function(){
                        $('#logMeOut').on('click',function(){
                            $.ajax({
                                url:'/usr/logMeOut',
                                method:'POST',
                                headers:{
                                    'X-CSRFToken':'{{csrf_token}}'
                                }
                            }).done(function(msg){
                                console.log(msg)
                                document.location='/'
                            }).fail(function(err){
                                alert(err)
                            })
                        })
                    })

                </script>

            {% endif %} </th>

    </ul>

        </div>
</body>

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

</html>
```

Comment: you need to pass `{'sections':sections,'authed':authed}` to the `base.html` also

Comment: how to send it to the base.html also ?
i know that it can return once right ?

Comment: Any time you need something on every page, it is easiest to write a custom context processor.  Here is a good example:  https://labofcoding.com/how-write-and-use-custom-template-processors-django/

Comment: in the view which render the `base.html` ,there you have to pass sections through `dictionay` like you did with your `home`  function.`OR` if you want to use this in your all template with only one function then you can use `context_processor` for this

Comment: i don't have a function that render to base.html

Comment: Note, this doesn't really need separate code at all. You could quite easily do it all within the template, since the request is available there: `{{ request.session.group }}`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman this was it thank you. i did not pay attention to it.